# ERROR: SERVER CLOSED THE CONNECTION UNEXPECTEDLY

Tags: sql, postgresql

When i connect to the server on `PostgreSQL` i get this error:

```
Server closed the connection unexpectedly. 
This probably means the server termitate abnormally before or 
while processing the request
```

If someone could help me i would appreciate it.
Thank you

Comment: Anything in the Postgres (server) log file?

Comment: i can't copy the log, it's too long, how can i copy it? thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when running postgres locally on win2k

[see here](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/KHEIKOKBEDHELABAIIMOAEDECDAA.carla@future-web-solutions.net)

Comment: Is there any solution to the problem?
This doesn't happen all the time, sometimes i get the error others i don't..
the OS is windows server 2007 standard.