# postgres, server closed the connection unexpectedly via VBS

Tags: postgresql, performance, vbscript, server, monitoring

I get this error:

"server closed the connection unexpectedly This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request."

Using this VBScript (vbs):

```
dim cn
set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")  
cn.ConnectionString= "DSN=dsn_name_here" 
cn.open 
cn.CommandTimeout = 28800

cn.execute("vacuum analyze fund_data;")
cn.execute("vacuum analyze daily_data;") '<-- error here
```

This line runs fine:
`cn.execute("vacuum analyze fund_data;")`

But this line errors:
`cn.execute("vacuum analyze daily_data;")`

I think I know why and how to prevent it, but I was wondering if there is a **better solution** and how to definitively determine the **root cause**.

I think the cause is related to lack of resources. `daily_data` is a much bigger table than `fund_data` and I have two other rather large queries running when this one errors, one of which also fails with this same error. I am thinking too much is going on at once, but how do I determine the root cause? Is it lack of disk space? (I know we don't have enough RAM so I think the queries are writing to disk. We are discussing upgrading our server, but I want to understand and able to diagnose.) Is there a way to determine the root definitively?

I think the solution is to just time the queries differently so they aren't running at the same time. The issue there is that because we are starved for resources everything is running slowly and the daily schedule is overbooked as it is and I need to sneak some `vacuum`s in. Is there a better way from a scripting standpoint (or DBA standpoint) without getting into the details of the actual queries?

Why doesn't postgres just slow down or lock the queries rather than terminating them? Or is something else going no?

PS - I'll move this question to SO DBA site if that is a better fit, but I thought I would try asking the question from a scripting perspective first.

**EDIT1:** What I am running:

from pgadmin:

```
select version();
PostgreSQL 9.6.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16), 64-bit
```

from the terminal of the virtual server that PostgreSQL is installed on:

```
lsb_release -a
LSB Version: n/a
Distributor ID: SUSE LINUX
Description: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12
Release: 12
Codename: 12

uname -r
3.12.28-4-default
```

The VBScript is run from a Windows 7 laptop.

Do I have something wrong?

**EDIT2:**

I updated my odbc drivers here:
https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/

And they now have (didn't notice what I had prior to updating):

`%WINDIR%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` Drivers tab has PostgreSQL ANSI(x64) 9.06.05.00 and PostgreSQL Unicode(x64) 9.06.05.00

`%WINDIR%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` Drivers tab has has PostgreSQL ANSI 9.06.05.00 and PostgreSQL Unicode 9.06.05.00

Rebooted the laptop with the new drivers and setup a foreign data table to my server log files via this good, but slightly inaccurate link:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153904/pgadmin-4-server-status-view-log-file

...so I can provide some server logs tomorrow.

**EDIT 3:**

In addition to the EDIT 2, I restarted the server.

I successfully created the error this morning. Same exact thing as before. Server logs show nothing about a `vacuum` query:

```
select * from postgres_log 
where query like '%vacuum%'
```

However, like it always does, the `vacuum` and one other query that "errors" at the same time, still show up in `pg_stat_activity`:

```
select pid,query,state,wait_event,* from pg_stat_activity where state <> 'idle'
```

By "errors" I mean I get the error in the original question, but the queries still seem to run. At least the vacuum does for sure.

And eventually, if I check my `vacuum`s it completes the vacuum under `last_vacuum`. I can see this via the date from this query:

```
 select relname,last_vacuum, last_autovacuum, last_analyze, last_autoanalyze from pg_stat_user_tables order by relname;
```

So I think the server thinks the query is fine. To me, it seems like something in the script. The `vacuum` is running right now by the way with no state change since the query started, but this query usually completes.

What could this be? What other information do you need?

Also, I don't think it is important, but at the time of the error I am running queries from VBA and VBS simultaneously.

**EDIT 4:**

After investigating by time:

```
 select * from postgres_log where session_start_time > '2017-09-29 06:00:00'
```

I find 5 server logs with "using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding".

Note: nothing else was logged by the server during the error in question.

I quick search on that error I found this:
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1457523467.24545.43.camel%402ndquadrant.com

Sounds like my "I/O system is overloaded"?

**EDIT 5:**

I am not sure if this matters, but at about this time we experience some general LAN slowness/messaging issues.

Specifically, it is a completely different process that runs using the same LAN as my original question above. For details:
https://serverfault.com/questions/873296/saving-large-excel-files-to-network-drive-locks-on-saving-progress-bar-popup

Could this be related?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR: SERVER CLOSED THE CONNECTION UNEXPECTEDLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763378/error-server-closed-the-connection-unexpectedly)

Comment: Looks to be unrelated to VBScript - [Postgre SQL odbc driver - Server closed the connection Unexpectedly](//stackoverflow.com/q/38087593). Check the driver and maybe update if using an old one.

Comment: @Lankymart - see EDIT1 regarding your first comment. Just seeing your second comment. Updating my odbc driver now. Will report back. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: To be honest, the VBScript code isn't great, you create an `ADODB.Command` object set the timeout then never use it, instead the query is fired using the `ADODB.Connection` object's `Execute()` method. The `cmDB` object does nothing in the above code. This wouldn't cause the issue with PostgreSQL though.

Comment: Thanks @Lankymart. I am seeing that now. This is legacy code that needs some clean-up. I'll make the change in the script. Should I clean it up in the question too? I also updated the odbc driver and I am testing it now.

Comment: Please show the entries from your **server** log when the problem occurs.

Comment: @DanielVérité - Getting to the server logs is no simple task in postgres, apparently. As soon has I can change my `log_destination` I will follow these instructions to get the server logs via a query, but for now it "cannot be changed now" (because i have queries running?): https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153904/pgadmin-4-server-status-view-log-file

Comment: Above you gave `lsb_release` obtained through a terminal on the virtual server. Why not use the terminal to look at the server logs without changing anything?

Comment: @DanielVérité - because I find moving information from the terminal window via vSphere HyperVisor to SO for the post is a huge pain. Also, I work in pgAdmin so much it's nice to have everything at my fingertips. FYI - I got the log_destination set, but I had to kill all my test queries and reboot the server to have the settings all take. I'll probably have some server log error info to post tomorrow since the test takes 3 or 4 hours to produce an error.

Comment: @DanielVérité - I added edit 3 and 4. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Lankymart - I updated the odbc drivers and got the same error.

Comment: The question was: At the exact time that the client side gets the error _server closed the connection unexpectedly_, what is being put by the server in the server side logs, if anything? The point is that such error is generally obtained when the server crashes, and when it happens it tries to log information on the crash.

Comment: @mountainclimber the other thing mentioned in those articles is specifying the port number explicitly in the connection string *(not sure how you do that in a dsn)*.

Comment: @DanielVérité - just added "Note: nothing else was logged by the server during the error in question." See edit 4. Just the log statement about the stats collector, as mentioned in edit 4. Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: @Lankymart - the port is defined in the System DSN configuration like seen here (from image I found online...this isn't my config): https://www.vasco.com/images/120223-img-1_tcm42-55377.PNG

Comment: I have seen this on unreliable networks before. When the server logs nothing when the client says the server closed the connection this is because the server didn't close the connection. Something else did. The server is blissfully unaware and will continue executing the query is working on and only discovers it has lost connection with the client when it tries to send the result. So the server side error can come much later then the error on the client.

Comment: @Eelke - interesting. Thank you. My last test got messed up so I am rerunning it now to get some clean logs. What type of error would you expect to see once the server realizes what happened? Also, would the server show a log error eventually still if all of the queries running didn't return anything? The queries are all just updates, inserts, and vacuums.

Comment: Message would be something like "Client closed the connection unexpectedly". Queries that do not return tuples still send a result to the client to signal they are ready and wether the command succeeded or failed.

Comment: @Eelke - that was it: connectivity/unreliable network. Since I "improved the network" the error hasn't occurred and things are progressing nicely.  Can you make an answer? I'll give you cred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Eelke mentioned in comments, the issue was lack of network reliability. A connection (established via vbs in this case) that is interrupted/broken due a network outage can cause this type of error in a program (vbscript in this case) but not produce any immediate server-side errors:

"server closed the connection unexpectedly This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request."

Solution: make the network more reliable

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a solution to set the below configuration parameters

**tcp_keepalives_idle (integer)**

Specifies the number of seconds of inactivity after which TCP should send a keepalive message to the client. A value of 0 uses the system default. This parameter is supported only on systems that support TCP_KEEPIDLE or an equivalent socket option, and on Windows; on other systems, it must be zero. In sessions connected via a Unix-domain socket, this parameter is ignored and always reads as zero.

**tcp_keepalives_interval (integer)**

Specifies the number of seconds after which a TCP keepalive message that is not acknowledged by the client should be retransmitted. A value of 0 uses the system default. This parameter is supported only on systems that support TCP_KEEPINTVL or an equivalent socket option, and on Windows; on other systems, it must be zero. In sessions connected via a Unix-domain socket, this parameter is ignored and always reads as zero.

**tcp_keepalives_count (integer)**

Specifies the number of TCP keepalives that can be lost before the server's connection to the client is considered dead. A value of 0 uses the system default. This parameter is supported only on systems that support TCP_KEEPCNT or an equivalent socket option; on other systems, it must be zero. In sessions connected via a Unix-domain socket, this parameter is ignored and always reads as zero.

Answer (score -1):

[image: If this is the error you are getting:]

The solution that solved this was for me was to change this setting in the ODBC connection from the default of 1 to 0:

`UseServerSidePrepare=0`